# Connecting to a hokuyo laser separate from the robot

Tags: ros, p3dx, hokuyo-node, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im trying to connect to a hokuyo range finder that is connected to a pioneer p3dx robot. My problem is that the robot does not have an onboard computer I can access, so I usually connect to it using ip/port combination. I can connect to the robot using ROSARIA but when it comes to communicating with the laser, I'm not certain on how to provide the port to the hokuyo_node, because its not located on a local port (e.g /dev/....) but an external one (e.g ip/port)

I would really appreciate if someone could enlighten me on how to make this work.

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55815/connecting-to-a-hokuyo-laser-separate-from-the-robot/) by [cf.morales46](https://answers.ros.org/users/3592/cf.morales46/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

There is a problem with the hoyuko_node; it cannot support the ethernet devices yet.
Instead use the urg_node (this supports ethernet) .. you can find it online

Install this node; after that connect the lidar via ethernet cable with your computer. You must ensure that you're on the same subnet as the LIDAR. (you can change this in the settings for your computer). For example, if you're lidar has the ip address 192.168.0.10, make sure your computer is set to something like 192.168.0.2.

the launch the node as rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.10"; it will start streaming data (again, if it does not, check your IP address). If you cannot find it in settings, you can change it manually in /etc/network/interfaces.

Then check using rostopic list .. you will see scans like /first /last and /most_intense.

After this, fire up rviz, set the fixed frame to /laser, add LaserScan and set its topic to /first etc..

Hope this helps

-Pranav

---

Originally posted by [Pranav Bhatkhande](https://answers.ros.org/users/4935/pranav-bhatkhande/) with karma: 36 on 2013-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2